# How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?

Tags: codecs, multimedia, aac, h264

Where do I get the MPEG-4 AAC decoder, and the H.264 decoder.

How to install them and play the multimedia?

Comment: This thread is hilarious, everyone has as different proposition of packages to install and I don't think any of them work, I haven't found a combination that works yet anyhow.  I gave-up and loaded an MP3 stream instead.

Answer (score 159):

**ubuntu-restricted-extras** package allows users to install ability to play popular non-free media formats, including DVD, MP3, Quicktime, and Windows Media formats.

To install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package:

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Run this command:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
   ```
3. Alternatively, you can install the package via **Software Center** by launching it via **Dash** and searching the package and clicking on **Install**.

[image]

Also, try installing **libavcodec54** **libav-tools** and **ffmpeg** with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec54 libav-tools ffmpeg
```

#### EDIT: Ubuntu *20*.04+

In Ubuntu ***20.04*** onwards, you want `libavcodecXX` instead of `54`:

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec58 ffmpeg # Ubuntu 20.04
sudo apt-get install libavcodec59 ffmpeg # Ubuntu 22.04
sudo apt-get install libavcodec60 ffmpeg # Ubuntu 23.10
```

You can use `apt search libavcodec` to find the current version for your particular installation.

Comment: Is `ubuntu-restricted-extras` enough for mp4 playback from Twitch.tv? Or do I need the `libavcodec54 libav-tools ffmpeg` as well? @Peachy

Comment: Also: Package libav-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ffmpeg:i386 ffmpeg

E: Unable to locate package libavcodec54
E: Package 'libav-tools' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Shayan Are you also on Ubuntu **20**.04?

Comment: @Nathan I wrote these comments back when I was using 16.04.3 and still am using it.

Comment: Ah, okay.  As edited-in above, I solved this for Ubuntu 20.04.  For Ubuntu 20.04, you've gotta do `sudo apt-get install libavcodec58` instead of 54

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 libav-tools has no installation candidate

Comment: For me on 20.04 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libavcodec58 ffmpeg
Finished the job, video app is now playing videos.

Comment: You may also have to refresh your shell for it to work.  `exec bash` or `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I would not install it. It installs hel of a lot executable & some fonts. Why do I need executables is that windows or .net mono/core?

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Libavcodec is now libavcodec59 (and presumably it'll increase in future: just `apt search libavcodec` to find the latest version available)

Comment: It worked like charm on ubuntu 20.04. Thank you

Comment: @Shayan The libav fork was dead; everybody switched back to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 37):

Support to decode `MPEG-4 AAC` is provided by [gstreamer1.0-libav](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gstreamer1.0-libav&searchon=names) and to decode `H.264` there is [ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ffmpeg&searchon=names):

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav ffmpeg
```

For more information have a look at the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

Comment: Excellent on Ubuntu 20.04.1, Thanks.

Comment: Besides these packages I installed `libavcodec58` package too, I face an issue into Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: best solution on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 26):

The other answers seems to work on older versions but today when I was installing the same on clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 using Peachy's answer I got lot of errors. Using these commands I installed that in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS successfully.

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

**Note:** In 20.04, libdvdread4 has been updated to libdvdread7, and in 20.10, it's now libdvdread8 (see [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libdvdread) for the current version).

Comment: This actually works for 18.04. Thanks bro!!

Comment: I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS, and I have installed all the pieces of software you mentioned here, but... The problem is still the same! VLC player can play those videos but not Parole. So...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This also worked for Ubuntu 20. I had the same issue with a new install

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately none of these options seem to work on Ubuntu 16.04.
I get a python 3.5 message for searching MPEG-4 AAC in one of the videos I try to play. None of the above fixing the missing codec.

A fine workaround is to install VLC:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

(or from software center)

Update: found a fix:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

This made sound work for Totem (Video)

Update: Try going to 'Software & Updates' and enabling the checkbox for 'Software restricted by by copyright or legal issues'. Then allow Ubuntu to update after clicking the close button. You should now be able to run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You'll also have to accept the EULA's terms and conditions before continuing.

Answer (score 5):

## Beware of the audio-only gstreamer bug

Hearing only audio on H.264 playback with an otherwise black video screen was reported as `gstreamer1.0` [bug #1562875](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0/+bug/1562875).

Luckily, this bug can easily be resolved by issuing the following command once:

```
$ rm -R ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

This will take effect after restarting the application.

Comment: I didn't help to me! I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS and Parole 1.0.1.

Comment: It helped and saved me after two days of researching. I was trying to play GTA SA on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In the last Ubuntu ver 14.04 , 14.10 the best way for setup them is :

To install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package:

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53 libavcodec53
```

and N-joy

Answer (score 1):

In my case I also needed `intel-media-va-driver-non-free` on top of the above answers
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Solved my problem in Ubuntu 22.04 to play old mpgeg videos. VLC didn't work well. With this installation, I can use the system's default player.