# How to install mpeg-4 aac and h.264 decoder on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I'm trying to play a video which requires the above mentioned plugins. I've looked at a few answers on this topic here but it hasn't resolved the issue for me.

What I've tried until now :

1. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`  ...  But this one's having some issues and skipping downloading some packages... so the whole thing doesn't get downloaded completely.
2. I've tried  `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"`  to add the above repositories to the ubuntu's source.list for download places but it hasn't helped.

Anyone knows what else can I try to get this working?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is not supported anymore, please use the latest version 12.10 or 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Difficult to get support for an unsupported version.

Comment: @UriHerrera - Do you mean a fresh install of ubuntu 12.10 / 12.04 LTS  or do you mean i need to get the codec packages meant for ubuntu's 12.x versions ?  I'll need help in the later case as i'm not sure where/how to download them...

Comment: Upgrade your OS, and install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

Comment: @UriHerrera Can i just run the update to upgrade the OS or does this need a fresh install ?

Comment: I would recommend a fresh install. If you upgrade through the Update Manager you have to go through each release 11.04>11.10>12.04 or 12.10, you can (but shouldn't) skip them.

Comment: ok thanks ... i'll set up myself for a couple of hours of time waste ... :)

Comment: This question is based on the question http://askubuntu.com/q/214421/217269 which was asked before. There are good answers provided too!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to download *codecs*. To install the proprietary *codecs* type the following in a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pitfdll gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
```

Once you have installed these *codecs* you will be able to play nearly any audio/video format.

I also recommend you to Upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: All of them contained in the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package..., did you tested this on Maverick? did this worked for you on Maverick?.

Comment: Yeah it did work on Maverick..

Comment: @Mukund - I tried the command for trhe 32 bit version, however i encountered the following errors. 1)There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes.  So i replaced -y with --force-yes and tried again...This time there's problem downloading certain packages i.e issue no. 2 2)Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/g/gst-plugins-ugly-multiverse0.10/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse_0.10.16-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80] Try runnning apt-get update or --fix-missing. So what next ?