# How to install h.264 decoder?

Tags: 12.04, video, python-2.7, h264

I tried playing videos in movie player but only the audio could be heard.
I tried playing the video with dragon player but here also only the audio could be heard.

A message box appeared showing the following message:

> Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: H.264 decoder

I tried installing the plugin but it couldn't be installed.
It isn't available in the software center too.
How can I get this plugin?

Comment: which video format you are trying to play?? and by the way have you installed Ubuntu-restricted-extras??

Comment: m trying to play MPEG-4 video (video/mp4)

Comment: yes the restrictd packages are installd

Comment: install h264enc causing the error as mentioned by rajagenupula..

Comment: The reader of this question might also want to have a look at the  question http://askubuntu.com/q/214421/217269 (about multimedia decoders)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the H.264 encoder, then

```
sudo apt-get install h264enc
```

will install H.264 in your system.

Comment: i tried 
aftr d whole procedure,postfix configuration popped up..but nothing hapened

Comment: Isn't this the encoder, not the decoder?

Comment: h264enc is "A shell script which makes it easy to encode DVDs or video files to the H.264/AVC/MPEG-4 Part 10 video format using MEncoder from the MPlayer project".  That doesn't sound like the codec that's wanted, but converting the videos might be a fallback option.

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get install h264enc`, but Ubuntu says it is not available.  Tried `apt-cache search h264enc` but got nothing.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson make sure you have "multiverse" repository enabled. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=h264enc

Comment: *DEcoder not ENcoder

Answer (score 35):

In order to play H.264 encoded videos the corresponding decoder comes with the following library:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked!

Answer (score 7):

The package that fixed it for me on 16.04 is the gstreamer plugins bad.
I got a message about Python-3.5 minimal wanting to install some MPEG-4 AAC plugin, which did not do anything. To fix:
In a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

If you still can't get it to work somehow, you can try VLC as a workaround, installable by:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I did not unclick the restricted software, that may work but may disable other codecs.
By the way, movie player or Video is the Totem video player.

Comment: Worked on 20.04

Comment: VLC worked for me, mp4 videos were playing randomly, now everything looks correct with VLC. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is part of the package gstreamer-plugins-bad. If you search for this in Software Center it should show up. It might be that you have to activate the multiverse repository (start Software & Sources and tick the appropriate box for this).

After you have installed the package, Movie Player should be able to play the file.

Comment: the gstreamer-plugin that u mentiond is n being able to b instald..it shows some eror like this isnt availble in ur software

Comment: i tried something and now finally i can c d video...thnx alot everyone for ur help..:)

Comment: The package was probably not available because you hadn't activated the multiverse repository, as I wrote you might have to do :)

Answer (score 4):

## The audio-only gstreamer bug can easily be resolved

Hearing only audio on H.264 playback with an otherwise black video screen was reported as `gstreamer1.0` [bug #1562875](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0/+bug/1562875).

Luckily, this bug can easily be resolved by issuing the following command once:

```
$ rm -R ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

This will take effect after restarting the application.

Comment: I installed all kinds of packages to no effect, and this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: finally , only thing that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Installing `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` from a PPA as described below solved this for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: It says: Package 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with playing videos. Video player wanted to download mpeg - 4 acc decoder and h.264 decoder, but this hadn`t happened due to legal reasons (-if I understand correctly what was written in the window what appears after pc was trying to download mentioned programs).

After I unclicked Software & updates -> Ubuntu software -> "unclick" Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse) all start working again. (I mean that after this operation pc downloads what he needed and that it started working).

Answer (score 0):

Following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk5viMViSXk) worked for me. Now, I am able to play and seek forward/backward h264 files created by my Chinese IP Camera.

To sum up:

- Open VLC.
- Go to: `Tools`/`Preferences`. Select `Show settings`: `All'
- In `Input / Codecs` / `Demuxers`, select `Demux module` as `h264 video demuxer`. Save and restart VLC.

Now you should be able to play h264 file.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Every website says to do this, but in Ubuntu 20.0.4, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do is Download & Install VLC layer from Ubuntu Software and enjoy your vedioenter image description here
Install VLC player
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrKWg.png
Open With VLC Player
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6vpE.png
Enjoy
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzg5d.png