# Unable to watch some videos on firefox ubuntu 19.1

Tags: firefox, video, flash, youtube

I just downlaoded Ubuntu 19.10,it came with Firefox 72.0.1 pre-installed, I can't watch some videos on YouTube although when I opened youtube.com/html5 it redirects me to this[image: youtube.com/html5], I checked some answers before,they include an add-on "OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc." but I can't find,I also got the error on skillshare.com [image: skillshare], I downloaded Chrome and the videos work fine there, Is there any new Solution that works on Firefox

Comment: Can you please provide a link of a failing video.  I use streaming from youtube in QA-testing Ubuntu flavors and don't have any issues (though I tend of view local news streams if not something offered on the first page)

Comment: @guiverc all videos that are on skillshare I can't play, however youtube most I can

Comment: I was interested in a youtube link that fails; I can test it with today's daily (20.04 & latest 18.04.4)  and if problems look at why (raising bug report etc).

Comment: not for firefox (which is fine with youtubes for me) but for opera I got facebook  and t\others to work in Opera. https://askubuntu.com/questions/384650/how-to-install-h-264-decoder