# 20.04 ubuntu video player says, "H.264" not supported

Tags: multimedia

20.04 ubuntu video player says, "H.264" not supported.  How can I fix ?
I got the error when I try mpeg2 format.
wemb format was ok.

Comment: See if this helps:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/384650/how-to-install-h-264-decoder

Comment: You may need to enable multiverse before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository

Answer (score 5):

For me, I just installed VLC.

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

If you want to use the default players, I heard installing the Ubuntu Restricted Extras should install all the codecs that couldn't be shipped with Ubuntu. (It didn't work for me, though...)

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

gl :)