# libavcodec - codec not found

Tags: video, ffmpeg, c

I am trying to run [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/encode_video_8c-example.html) program from ffmpeg c documentation. It is compiled successfully. But showing "codec not found" when I am trying to execute. I am using below command to compile.

```
gcc -o video_encode video_encode.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lm
```

I use following command to run this file.

```
./video_encode videoplayback mpeg-4
```

I used the codec mpeg4 like

```
./video_encode videoplayback mpeg4
```

You can see the result in image

[click here to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMbm2.png)

But it is showing codec 'mpeg-4' and 'mpeg4' not found. I use different codecs available, still facing the same issue.  I have installed new versions of ffmpeg libavcodec and other related libraries and ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Please help me through this.

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder)?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use the H264 codec, and ran into a similar problem. I was sure the codec was installed on my machine, since I was able to encode with the `ffmpeg` CLI without any issues.

What fixed the problem was to add `av_register_all()` before looking the codec up:

```
/* find the mpeg1video encoder */
codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);
// codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name);
    exit(1);
}
// rest of the program...
```

Comment: I think you meant `avcodec_register_all`. Older versions of ffmpeg require that. Newer examples will be missing this.

Answer (score 1):

## compile

A simple guide:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
./configure
make -j4 examples
```

- This will compile all of the examples in-tree using the source code from the current git master branch and may be less error prone than using `gcc`.
- The `compile` and `make` commands will take several minutes to complete.
- For more info see `doc/examples/README`.
- As doug mentioned the example in question is named `encode_video.c`.

## encoder name

The codec name is *mpeg4* (no hyphen). See `ffmpeg -encoders` for a list of encoder names supported by your particular build.

Comment: Hi, First of all, thanks for answering. Yes I tried like you said, it is still giving me the same issue. Tried with all the codecs available. You can suggest me or you can say where I can get the exact code which I need to convert this video into images in c language.

Comment: Hi @LordNeckbeard, so you want me to install the pkg-config? Compiling and executing requires this package? what's this package exactly does? is it because of compatibility issues?

Comment: @emb-pro pkg-config helps locate libraries, and you may already have it installed. You may not need it depending on the configure options you use when you compile ffmpeg, but it is recommended to make things easier.

Comment: How can I see the images from this program? Do I need any extra modifications to capture the pictures?

Comment: @emb-pro It really depends on the encoder you chose, but mpeg4 should be playable by just about any desktop player. Sorry, but I don't understand your second question.

Comment: I have seen a code [here](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/blob/master/0_hello_world.c). I executed it. It creates no.of images based on frame rate. Like this, I want to produce images from [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/encode_video_8c-example.html).

Comment: @emb-pro You should ask the [libav-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html). It is the mailing list for FFmpeg library & API users and questions about programatic usage. My answer was specifically trying to resolve the "codec not found" issue. Did you resolve that?

Comment: Yes, I resolved it. The program didn't have the line av_register_all().

Answer (score 1):

Are you building "video_encode" in or out of tree? If later you'd need to have libavcodec-dev installed. If former then you'd first need to build the ffmpeg source. Based on you using a gcc command I'd guess out of tree.

Note that it's actually named `encode_video.c` in the ffmpeg source ( no matter.

Works fine here in an out of tree build to produce the expected encoding ( i.e, 1 sec.

Ex.

`$ ./video_encode videotest.m4v  mpeg4
Send frame   0
Send frame   1
Write packet   0 (size= 6467)
Send frame   2
Write packet   2 (size= 3281)
Send frame   3
Write packet   1 (size= 1874)
Send frame   4
Write packet   4 (size= 3579)
Send frame   5
Write packet   3 (size= 2069)
Send frame   6
Write packet   6 (size= 4389)
Send frame   7
Write packet   5 (size= 2204)
Send frame   8
Write packet   8 (size= 3538)
Send frame   9
Write packet   7 (size= 2348)
Send frame  10
Write packet  10 (size=13024)
Send frame  11
Write packet   9 (size= 2303)
Send frame  12
Write packet  12 (size= 4718)
Send frame  13
Write packet  11 (size= 2504)
Send frame  14
Write packet  14 (size= 5082)
Send frame  15
Write packet  13 (size= 1898)
Send frame  16
Write packet  16 (size= 4186)
Send frame  17
Write packet  15 (size= 1842)
Send frame  18
Write packet  18 (size= 4676)
Send frame  19
Write packet  17 (size= 1782)
Send frame  20
Write packet  20 (size=12942)
Send frame  21
Write packet  19 (size= 2237)
Send frame  22
Write packet  22 (size= 5180)
Send frame  23
Write packet  21 (size= 2312)
Send frame  24
Write packet  24 (size= 4520)
Write packet  23 (size= 2523)`

[image]
`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do I need to reinstall the libraries again, like libavcodec-dev. But Why I am getting the errors like this? Is it because of the codecs missing? or libraries missing?

Comment: Well install libavcodec-dev and try again. You do understand that that code is just an example, you can't use it as is to 'convert' a video. All its going to do is create a 1 sec test video

Comment: Thank you @doug, I got the exact output. But how can I see the images?

Comment: In the folder that has the 'video_encode` binary there would be a 1 sec long video that looks like attached..