# Parole asks for extra software to decode MPEG4-AAC videos

Tags: video, codecs

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS and Parole 1.0.1.

Some kind of 4K UltraHD videos I had downloaded from YouTube, produce the following effect:

Parole asks me for extra software to decode MPEG-4 AAC.

Then Parole tells me that it can be possible to install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, what is open inmediately.

BUT... All the possible software (GStreamer Multimedia Codecs) to perform the decoding action are already installed!

So...

How can I  fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder because you probably need to install a few things.

Comment: I see that item and I have already installed all the indicated software. Nothing helps to me! So...