# Why no sound on one computer?

Tags: sound, video-player

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on 2 separate computers.  On one of them I play a video and it seems to play all formats, and on the internet, youtube, there is sound.
On the other computer, there is no sound.  I went to the sound configuration and selected the output device.  But no sound.  AND in the video player, it will not play mpg files.  It just quits.  When installing it did select for it to add the other codecs (or whatever that installation option was).  I did run the application updater.
One plays all videos with sound, the other no sound and won't play mpg.  What did I miss?

Comment: Well, I think I may have dicsovered the difference as far as sound goes.  One has speakers connected to the audio output jack and one is just connected through HDMI.  But that still leaves the mystery of why one plays all videos and why the other doesn't

Comment: Have you tried this to make sure the proper codecs are installed? https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder