# How do I install h.264 decoder?

Tags: gnome, video, codecs

I am using 20.04 GNOME. I tried to delete VLC with aptitude, which also somehow deleted h.264 decoder required to play some videos.

So I can't play videos on my machine any more. I've downloaded everything from `h.264` as `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav`, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa: mc3man / trusty-media`. They appear as downloaded but there is no `h.264`.

How do I install h.264 decoder so I can play the videos again?

[image: h.264]

Comment: Trusty is End of Life (EOL) and you should not have added that PPA. You could simply have used `sudo apt install vlc` to get current version for your Ubuntu. I would remove the Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) PPA and try again.

Comment: I probably fall into a limbo of settings, I think there is no way .... only if I went back in time with my configuration but I had to have backed up, probably ... I downloaded everything available on the internet to solve it .... I managed to delete the VLC, but the plugins were left and the decoder 264, this one was lost.

Comment: just a last detail, I realized that this has nothing to do with the video extension, as there are files of mine that have the extension ".mp4" that they execute and some others that do not, as well as ".webm" ... I I can use my webcam and play my created videos, but otherwise, it won't let me ... it shows that h.264 is missing ... just out of curiosity... stranger

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/12U7WJ1Af_uv22AcTjJCxA61du73wppYx/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: the video on the right executes and the video on the left does not ... punk

Comment: [Does this help you install h.264?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072894/25798)