# Error while installing new packages in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

04 and I was trynna install a Screen recorder in my ubuntu. I installed SimpleScreenRecorder and when I was trying to record the files there was this error `"H.264 decoder is required to play this file."` So I tried to fix it by using commands : `"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras"`

Link to the website I got to know about SimpleScreenRecorder: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/02/28/install-simple-screen-recorder-ubuntu-16-04-16-10/

Link to the command I got for solving the problem: [How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder)

After I did the command I found out that the command I ran was for ubuntu 18 so maybe that's why the problem is coming. Now i have this thing on my notification: `"An error occurred, please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. Error: Broken count>0. This usually happens when you install packages that have unmet dependencies."`

Problems that is occurring when i try to install any package from terminal:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 11285 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Note: I am super new with Linux and i don't know anything, please have patience with me. Thank you

Comment: Yes it helped, thank you @karel

Comment: If the duplicate link answered your question please confirm it by clicking "Yes" next to where it says "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.