# After installing dvd source for playing dvd's I got this!

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

I installed restricted extras, multiverse, other codecs over a week period periodically found out how to get libdvdcss2, and libdvdread4, both where not supplied by the terminal, bash or shell. libdvdcss2 was installed by a Firefox hot linking method-2. libdvdcss2 was then installed via Ubuntu Software, libdvdread4 found via; "pkgs.org" apparently generic 18.04 .deb file installer. Was was wondering? Why are these codecs no longer in repositories or terminal bash shell for Ubuntu 20.04 or 21 editions? I had some really bad DVD playback as in the below image with XBMC's new Kodi player, an menu options with VLC. SMplayer played the DVD correctly, although it could not highlight menu options with the mouse cursor at all. I tried many other video players. They all have similar results, a trashed screen with weird lines and blue people looking like the smurfs.

This happened once a long time ago as well, using Lubuntu 12.04 way back when. The fix was switching to 32-bit i386 architecture from
amd64. If that's the case can Ubuntu bring back 32-bit architecture and just enable pae for extra processors! I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on an eight core processor ASUS motherboard. It's a brand new rig too!

Update: I found a way. It was a nightmare to find it: [How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder) "How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?" and https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/h-264-decoder-in-ubuntu-20-10/18017 "H.264 decoder in Ubuntu 20.10".

Also try installing libavcodec54 libav-tools and ffmpeg with this command:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec54 libav-tools ffmpeg
```

In Ubuntu 20.04, you want libavcodec58 instead of 54:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec58 libav-tools ffmpeg
```

Answers found; " [MPV media player loading dvd files directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHLRK.jpg)

[MPV plays dvds's vlc gets buggy errors][3]

VLC and Kodi's XBMC when playing DVD:

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: "*Was was wondering? Why are these codecs no longer in repoitories or terminal bash shell for ubuntu ver's 20.04*"  The codecs are available in later releases; just higher versions of the packages - did you look https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libdvdread&searchon=names

Comment: Still glitches with vlc ( https://archive.vn/YbPGQ/9a1499010c080af0240bc440648a7dbe7e653cbb.png ) and xbmc with kodi softwares. Mpv is the only one working 100% https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHLRK.jpg

Comment: I find your question hard to follow; PAE was always available for i586/i686; even before your mentioned 12.04.  It might be easier if you removed the (*rather error prone*)  unrelated opinions/details; though I suspect you've created the issue by installing  inappropriate packages creating issues (such as *bionic* packages instead of *focal* that led to my first comment).

Comment: Celluloid (formerly GNOME MPV) is a simple GTK+ frontend for mpv. It aims to be easy to use while maintaining high level of configurability.



Supports HDMI-dvd playback 2021.

https://celluloid-player.github.io/

Comment: Uninstalled vlc and xbmc, use videos app, mpv, celluloid now. They just work on more new hardware. [Remove] and [Purge] commands.

Comment: @guiverc I useually use devuan or debian these days on laptops, ubuntu seems to be only linux os to recognize HD televison sets. or roku tvs.

Comment: @guiverc  It is mostly web pages on duckduck go, or google, they put out to install these codecs on many articles. Some ol' some new.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@JesterObserver || Vlc and xbmc is very bad on 64bit linux, i'v had those problems too! Lines left and right, blue colored images on all computers. || @JesterObserver

It has been problem sense 12.04 days in ubuntu, 18.04 has to be the worst version though, for blue smurfs, screen taring.

Comment: @linuxuser01x001 This seems to be a problematic error, with Ubuntu and lubuntu  software in general. Yep! Same thing!

Comment: @linuxuser01x001 All the down votes, the truth must hurt!

Comment: @linuxuser01x001 Then they list me as a bot!? *shocked*