# After installing Ubuntu 22.04, the default video player is unable to play any videos

Tags: gnome, video, 22.04, codecs

The default video player (Totem) is unable to play videos after installing Ubuntu 22.04. I tried opening an MP4 file and I get the error (also shown in the screenshot):

> **An error occured**
>
> The specified movie could not be found.

[image: error in default video player]

I also tried installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, but it's still not working.

Comment: @user2983060 Try seeing if VLC can play the video. It can play _almost anything_. I really mean it - it is designed to play almost anything, even files 'normal' video players can't

Comment: Hi @cocomac, thanks buddy, VLC is working fine but what's wrong with the default video player?

Answer (score 98):

This is a known issue for Ubuntu 22.04: [Ubuntu 22.04 - totem 41.alpha.0 - The specified movie could not be found](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/-/issues/509)

There are also bug reports on Launchpad about it, which I suggest you subscribe to, so that they get more heat and hopefully get dealt with more quickly:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1969512
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1971463

The workaround for the moment is to either use the [Flatpak version of Totem](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Totem) or another video player, such as VLC, mpv, etc.

**Update 23/05/2022:**

As [Samuel Simon commented in 19/05/2022](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1969512/comments/21) in the first bug report above:

> Run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
> ```
>
> Got my solution from this article, check it out too.
> https://www.makeuseof.com/things-to-do-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-2204-lts/

<sup>Thanks [@Manuel](https://askubuntu.com/users/171961/manuel) for mentioning this workaround in [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410094/618353).</sup>

Comment: `sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi` saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Removing `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` immediately fixed the problem.

Comment: `sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi `did not work for me. My problem still persists.

Comment: I installed totem via  flathub. Videos tatred playing iside Totem, My problem was that videos embedded in beamer latex presentation were not playing. Installing VLC did not help as videos in beamer still could not play inside it. Later on I tried this `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` from this youtube video https://youtu.be/t0sgtQXyNJQ. Videos work now when clicked, but they open in a different window. Well something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 35):

As pointed in the [second link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1969512) of the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406276/171961) given by @BeastOfCaerbannog, a [solution for PCs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1969512/comments/21) (no Raspberry Pi, as [pointed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1969512/comments/23) in the same thread) is to remove `gstreamer1.0-vaapi`:

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

Here is the [original article](https://www.makeuseof.com/things-to-do-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-2204-lts/).

Comment: This didn't work for me. My mp4 videos played for a bit and then hung, with the sound continuing! The snap version of vlc didn't work either; it never appeared to start. What worked for me in the end was `sudo apt install vlc` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1412874/103266)

Comment: Forgot to say: then make VLC Media Player your default application for videos in ubuntu's settings; otherwise Videos will keep trying to run when you double-click on mp4 files.

Comment: I think that it will be valuable for other people if you write your commented solution as an answer

Comment: Maybe. It follows on directly from yours since I tried your answer first and then didn't undo it. Maybe if I had undone your suggestion first a different approach would've worked.

Comment: I had a very specific occurrence: Switch game mp4 video captures generated from the Smash Ultimate video library "Convert to Video" feature would cause an error "this file cannot be played over the network" (and *only* those - mp4 captured using the recording feature in other games like Zelda would play fine!) when played with standard video player. VLC plays them fine. Removing `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` also fixes this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove `gstreamer1.0-vaapi`, but that also didn't work. I read from an Ubuntu bug report that I should use something like:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 totem
```

So I played with `3.3`, `3.2`, until this worked for me using the shell:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.1 totem
```

My system's details:

[image: Settings About]