# Movies not shown properly by Videos app

Tags: graphics, 22.04, video-player

Since I upgraded to 22.04, some movie files in mp4 format are not shown correctly by the standard Videos app (formerly "Totem").

[image]

VLC has no problem with these files. Other mp4 files will play fine in Videos. As far as I can see, both the files that have problems, and those that don't, have the `mp4` extension and use the `H.264` codec. Sound is fine. Also, no error message is shown on the command line (`totem filename.mp4`).

I guess the difference is that the faulty ones are downloaded from Twitter. On the Twitter site and in Tweetdeck, they play fine, but once downloaded they don't.

I'm running Wayland on a Thinkpad with Intel® Core™ i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4 and Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2). Any ideas?

EDIT: an mp4 file that doesn't play, when uploaded into Whatsapp or Signal, will play without a hitch. Must be a bug in Videos then?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1406254

Comment: The issue has gone away now. I don't know which update caused it.