# How can I play videos with Totem on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, video-player, totem

The default video player (Totem) is unable to play videos after installing Ubuntu 22.04. I tried opening an MP4 file and I get the error:

> An error occured
>
> The specified movie could not be found.

I also tried installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, but it's still not working.

Comment: There are many to choose and you should do some interweb searches but for safest video playback I would recommend VLC `sudo apt-get install vlc` and follow the prompts.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [After installing Ubuntu 22.04, the default video player is unable to play any videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406254/after-installing-ubuntu-22-04-the-default-video-player-is-unable-to-play-any-vi/)