# Ubuntu 23.04 firefox PPA no decoder found for audio/mp4a-latm

Tags: sound, firefox, ppa

When I go to Proximus Live TV on my Ubuntu 23.04 laptop with Firefox 113.0.2 from
[https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=lunar](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=lunar)

Just running firefox from the command prompt I get below error message:

```
[Child 39570, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f5fe88d6f00 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - Error no decoder found for audio/mp4a-latm: file /build/firefox-USz78Y/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachineBase.cpp:164
```

The problem is that AAC SW is not in following list in about:support

[image]

While in SNAP version of firefox I get the list

[image]

I have no idea what causes this difference: the way how firefox is built in SNAP versus .deb ?

[Edited 2023/06/09]
This package ubuntu-restricted-extras made AAC SW available in VMware Workstation Guest Ubuntu 23.04.

But I can't get it working on my main Ubuntu 23.04, this package was already installed there. I thought there might be a conflict with nVIDIA driver or CUDA toolkit of my GeForce RTX 2060, but did not find anything on google about it.

Things that don't work in firefox from mozilla PPA on my main Ubuntu 23.04 are:

- Print to pdf makes file of size zero
- Save webpage makes file of size zero
- AAC SW and H264 SW are not present in about:support section Media

There must be some other directory where .deb firefox keeps its settings.
I already removed ~/.mozilla and got a brand new firefox, but still suffering from the same.

I read about /usr/lib/mozilla and on my laptop there is something left for the belgian identity card reader.

```
bert@legion5ubuntu:/usr/lib/mozilla/managed-storage$ ls -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  283 Feb 13 16:35 belgiumeid@eid.belgium.be.json

bert@legion5ubuntu:/usr/lib/mozilla/native-messaging-hosts$ ls -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  265 Jan  3 21:38 org.gnome.browser_connector.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  266 Jan  3 21:38 org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell.json

bert@legion5ubuntu:/usr/lib/mozilla/pkcs11-modules$ ls -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  209 Feb 13 16:35 beidpkcs11_alt.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  181 Feb 13 16:35 beidpkcs11.json
```

Would this directory be the root cause of the issues?

I am tired of switching between .deb and snap versions of firefox and would like to have more certainty on success when trying the .deb once more...

Any ideas of other directories where .deb firefox keeps its settings?

Comment: I wasted two evenings in trying to figure out what is wrong with this firefox from PPA.
I decided to go back to SNAP and of course there audio and video work great !

Comment: I am using Firefox 114 from this PPA https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, and I have all the eleven codecs identical those listed in the snap package.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Do you have special codecs installed that are not in a default Ubuntu installation?

Comment: I had installed the package `ubuntu-restrictred-extras` from the official repo, but nothing else.

Comment: To test this issue further I used VMware Workstation with Ubuntu 23.04 as host AND as guest. In the guest I installed "sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras" and now indeed the .deb Firefox has all the codecs and Proximus TV works fine. Still to try this on the main Ubuntu 23.04 because there this ubuntu-restricted-extras was already installed when I tried Firefox 113.0.2 from the PPA.

Comment: It is strange that Firefox 113.0.2 did not work. Can you add the PPA and update to the latest Firefox 114? There is works for me on several computers.

Comment: I installed 114 from PPA on my main Ubuntu 23.04. Still no AAC SW available here. But this Ubuntu has been upgraded every 6 months to the latest Ubuntu Release. And it still had old Mozilla data from the time where Firefox was still a .deb package before the SNAP Firefox came. I guess something in this old configuration is blocking AAC SW? I already refreshed (reset add-ons and settings) my firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try removing the directory `.mozilla` (you may lose your bookmarks unless signed in to Firefox) and clearing the cache?

Comment: Can you also try installing `libavcodec59` and `gstreamer1.0-libav` and `ffmpeg`? They are suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder

Comment: I installed libavcodec59 and removed .mozilla. Still same result only 9 codecs instead of 11.

Comment: I don't know what is causing these issues. I use Ubuntu 22.04 with the .deb version of Firefox, and never had any of these issues.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I edited the description under [Edited 2023/06/09]

Comment: & don't forget to restart the browser, after executing above command.